# Minimization constraints without using Lagrange Multiplier

Tags: constrained-optimization, constraints

Currently, I am working on an unconstrained energy minimization function, but I need to add some constraints. My system is a 2D lattice with a force applied to it, and I want the sides to be able to move, but the length of each side to be constant.

I know that using a Lagrange multiplier could make the terms I want to stay constant, constant by making the energy cost so huge that it won't move anything. But I was wondering if there was a different way to add constraints to the system without changing the fact that the energy minimization is unconstrained.

Comment: More like I want to add parameters to the unconstrained minimization.

Comment: In the lattice, there are nodes and bonds that connect them. A force is applied at the top and the lattice is allowed to have it's bonds stretch or bend. I want to make it so the bonds along only the sides cannot change length. I cannot simply let dx=dy=0 nor sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)=0 because the bending energy has mixed terms.

Comment: What about using a penalty method?

Comment: In addition to using penalty methods as @nicoguaro suggests, you could also transform the degrees of freedom to a different representation, such as bond angle + bond length rather than absolute position. A simpler case to try first would be the double pendulum, then the n-pendulum, then the full lattice. I think there are some helpful examples in Goldstein's classical mechanics book, or Hand and Finch *Analytical Mechanics*.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid multipliers?

Answer (score 4):

You want to convert a constrained problem into an unconstrained problem. There are two general techniques for this:

- If you have a constraint of the form $g(x_1,...,x_N)=0$, then you may be able to write it as $x_N=f(x_1,...,x_{N-1})$ and thereby simply *eliminate* one of the variables from your problem. You then don't need the constraint any more. (Of course, it may be that your constraint doesn't allow you to eliminate $x_N$ but another variable, with the same result.)
- You can *augment* your objective function by a penalty term that corresponds to your constraint. For equality constraints, this is most often done using a quadratic penalty, whereas for inequality constraints one most often uses a logarithmic penalty term. I would advise you to read through the book by Nocedal and Wright on "Numerical Optimization" to see how this works.